# Reference a variable within variable - hashes?

Tags: perl, variables, hash, reference

I have been looking for a solution to my problem and Hashes seem to be the answer after reading several posts but I am unsure how to implement this for my requirement, can anyone suggest how or even a better option?

In my code the variable `$host` is being set from values in a database. I loop through these values changing the value of `$host` each time.

I want to discard some types of host names, and to determine which hosts to discard I read in a user-configurable file which holds the Perl regex for that exclude. i.e. the config file has a line

```
 EXCLUDE=\d+DAT\d+,\d+INF\d+
```

I then want to build up the Perl regexp match (logical OR), i.e.

```
if ( $host =~ m/\d+DAT\d+/ || $host =~ m/\d+INF\d+/ ) {
  # do something
}
```

At the moment my code is hard wired as in the above example, but how can I dynamically construct the Perl regex after reading in the config file?

I have read the config file into an array and will start from there. The code above needs to end up like this:

```
if ($exclude clause) {
  # do something
}
```

This is how I set about achieving that reading from the array:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < @conf; $i++) {
  $exclude_clause .= "$host =~/" . @conf[$i] . "/ || "; 
}
$exclude_clause =~ s/ \|\| $//;
```

The problem is referencing `$host` within the `$exclude_clause`. My regex string is built OK apart from the `$host`.

Comment: What exactly is the problem ? and is this the actual code that you are trying to run ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different approach that doesn't require you to build up a big Regex string and then evaluate it. Instead, what about using the [`List::MoreUtils`](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/List-MoreUtils-0.33/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm) module's `any` function, which accepts a block of code, evaluates it for each member of a list, and returns true once the block returns true for at least one entry in the list. For example:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw{ any };

if ( any { $host =~ $_ } @conf ) {
    # do something
}
```

In the code block passed to `any`, the temp variable `$_` contains the current entry in the list. That way you can avoid constructing a Regex in the first place.

Comment: that sounds a neat solution, just to confirm - if my @conf array  values are \d+DAT\d+ (position 1) and \d+INF\d+ (pos2) etc. etc then each will be tested for a regexp match against $host & should any match then #do something.

Comment: I have just tried running the above suggestion and I am getting the error "Can't call method "any" without a package or object reference at........line 193" - line 193 is as follows:-

    if ( any { $host =~ m/$_/ } @conf){
     #do something
    }

I have installed List::MoreUtils and it is in my code "Use List::MoreUtils"

Any suggestions please?

Mark

Comment: I should have written `use List::MoreUtils qw{ any };`. Updated my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should store the complete regex in the configuration file, but it can be be a set of comma separated alternatives if need be.

You would use the `qr//` construct to build the regex:

```
my $exc1 = "\d+DAT\d+";  # Read from configuration file
my $ecc2 = "\d+INF\d+";

my $rex1 = qr/$exc1/;
my $rex2 = qr/$exc2/;

...populate $host...

if ($host =~ $rex1 || $host =~ $rex2)
{
    ...exclude $host...
}
else
{
    ...include $host...
}
```

Alternatively, you can build a single regex:

```
my $exc1 = "\d+DAT\d+";  # Read from configuration file
my $ecc2 = "\d+INF\d+";

my $rex = qr/$exc1|$exc2/;

...populate $host...

if ($host =~ $rex)
{
    ...exclude $host...
}
else
{
    ...include $host...
}
```

The single regex can be built from as many alternative exclusionary regex fragments as you like.  Of course, if the value in the file is:

```
EXCLUDE=\d+DAT\d+|\d+INF\d+
```

then your code simplifies once more, assuming the regex string is read into `$exc`:

```
my $exc = "\d+DAT\d+|\d+INF\d+";  # Read from file
my $rex = qr/$exc/;

...populate $host...

if ($host =~ $rex)
{
    ...exclude $host...
}
else
{
    ...include $host...
}
```